# Descartar las imágenes de preguntas/respuestas no publicadas

Tags: discusión, soporte, característica-nueva, stackexchange, imágenes

Perdón si las etiquetas no tienen nada que ver, pero trate de agregar cosas relacionadas, ya que no sabia donde podría estar esta pregunta, y que a la comunidad no le afecta en nada.

Estaba formulando una respuesta en la cual había subido una imagen para mostrar algo,
luego realice lo siguiente:

- Clic derecho
- Abrir imagen en una pestaña nueva

Y vi que ya estaba guardada en http://stack.imgur.com/ que es el servicio de almacenamiento que usan para las imágenes.

Lo que me hace subir esta pregunta es que me arrepentí de la respuesta y nunca la publique, pero las imágenes siguen guardadas.

¿No debería guardarse al presionar el botón de publicar la pregunta/respuesta? 
¿Puedo usar StackOverflow para almacenar mis imágenes?
¿No seria basura guardada?

También me pregunto...

¿Si realizo esto 100 veces, quedaran guardadas 100 imágenes nuevas?

No creo que sea bug, pero me llamo la atención porque no descartan esas imágenes en vez de guardarlas.

Comment: interesante... en tal caso los preocupados serian los de imgur que es a donde van a parar las imagenes... igual supongo que de vez en cuando borraran links muertos (si es que los pueden encontrar, no es algo tan trivial)... llegado el caso, esta seria una pregunta para meta general (ya que es una pregunta para todos los sitios, no solo este)... e igual, si ellos no se preocupan.. nosotros menos....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imgur y Stack Overflow son dos cosas distintas. Stack Overflow paga a Imgur para que le guarde las imágenes y no tiene un proceso más allá de subirlas y ya está. Dado que los borrados en Stack Overflow son "suaves" o "blandos" (se puede seguir viendo), no creo que tuviera sentido ir revisando el estado para proceder a la eliminación. En el caso de cosas no publicadas, la situación es parecida: durante el rato que va entre que subes la imagen y no le das a publicar y se acaba eliminando de la caché (que dura días), en cualquier momento puede pasar a ser una publicación.
Por tanto, una vez subes una imagen allí termina la visibilidad de Imgur y ya es un tema de Stack Overflow que se publique o no la publicación.

Si es algo que te preocupa especialmente, puedes pedir directamente a Imgur que te elimine una imagen a través de su servicio de [Removal Request - Imgur](https://imgur.com/removalrequest).